# how to select with bomb in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table with data like:

`A         B 
a1        b1
a2        b2`

I want to exe sql like :

`select A,B from test where A = 'a1'`

but a1 have a UTF-8 BOM, so I can not get data like (a1,b1).
I do not have the power to change data, so how to write sql like `where A = '???'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to issue

`ALTER TABLE test SET SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.encoding'='UTF-8');`

before your `SELECT` statement.

**Or** you can produce such a new table `test2` :

```
CREATE TABLE test2
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.encoding'='UTF-8')
AS SELECT * FROM test;
```

Comment: I only have read permission. I just want to know how to represent BOM in hql.